# Avoid revealing source code for CSHTML and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
   <body>
    <!-- some more CSHTML code here -->
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>
        var braintree = Braintree.create("SOME RANDOM KEY");
        braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to do the script without revealing the key string in the source.  I have a key, but I don't want it to be revealed.  Is there a safe and secure way to access a string by reference (preferably from a C# file)?  Sort of like:

```
    <script>
        var braintree = Braintree.create(somefile.getString("string_key"));
        braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code runs on the client, the key cannot be completely secure. A determined user could monitor network traffic and watch for the key when it arrived, or do one of 100 other things to compromise the key.

Comment: What do you recommend be the solution?  I still need a way to make it secure or at least as secure as I can for now.

Comment: One solution would be to route all traffic between you and Braintree through your own server and to keep the key on the server. That's been my approach for anything which requires keys like what you describe.


The question to ask is what the risk of your customers finding the key is. If it's low enough, the pass-through may not be worth the effort.

Comment: There are three other keys involved with this process, but that's all in the back-end.  I would assume that makes this key not as valuable (it's still very valuable...that's why I want it to be as hard to find as possible).  When you say keep this key on the server, do you mean on our server (and not BrainTree's server), correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Send the request to your server, possibly with a one-time key that you added at page load. The one-time key won't stop a determined attacker, but it will make casual bypass less likely. Once you are in an execution environment the client does not control, you can validate the request and pass it on to Braintree with the secret key.